# Remove 2 last digits and re-insert it to URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I struggle with htaccess problem - not really good at this.
My entire website structure localization and subdirectories was changed from

**domain.com/xy**

to

**subdomain.domain.com/xy/something/**

I struggle already for long time and cannot find solution to remove this 2 digits a.k.a country code  from inserted url and then reinsert it according to pattern.

Will be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: so you want to redirect domain.com/whatever  to subdomain.domain.com/whatever ?

Comment: Well almost - i whould like to take only 2 first digits of whatever so in that case WH